# render a string in MVC just like rendering a view, possible?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

is it possible to render a string like this:

```
public ActionResult Do(){
     s = " hello, click here <%=Html.ActionLink(\"index\",\"index\") %> ";

     return Content(RenderString(s));
}
```

the result would something like this:

```
hello, click here <a href="/home/index">index</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the purpose of this? You have a controller action which tries to evaluate some string WebForms syntax string and return it as content. Why not simply return the view and have this view do the job?

If you want dynamic to have views (coming from a database or something) you could write a [custom view engine](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Creating_a_Custom_View_Engine_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx) and personalize their location so that your action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Do()
{
    return View();
}
```

and the corresponding view contents will be fetched from your custom view engine instead of the standard file locations.

If you want to render the contents of a view into a string this has been covered in [many blog posts](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/render-partial-view-to-string-in-asp-net-mvc). Finally if you are dealing with sending views as emails there are probably [better solutions](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide).

So depending on what you are trying to achieve there might be different solutions.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov so this is not possible ?

Comment: @Omu, of course that it is possible. As I said in my answer depending on your final goal there are different techniques. Another one that I've missed is writing a custom [virtual path provider](http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2008/12/aspnet-mvc-plugins/). This `s` variable you have there, where is it coming from?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov s is coming from Database, basically users get messages that contain action links in them and since with time routing can be changed I ant them to be evaluated at the end

Comment: @Omu, then a custom VirtualPathProvider seems like a perfect candidate for implementing this.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov that's for rendering views from dlls, I want to render some string just like view, like rendering the content of a view without actually having the ascx file

Comment: @Omu, yes the example I provided is for rendering views embedded into assemblies. So all that's left to you is replace the part of the code that will fetch the view as embedded resource from your database.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov so this is the only way?, there is no simpler way, like having a method public static string RenderViewString(string content){}

Comment: @Omu, it is [possible with Razor](http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2010/7/22/using-the-razor-parser-outside-of-aspnet.html). There's also the [following project](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/). With the WebForms view engine much harder.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov I can user razor too, I wanted web-forms in the 1st place because with razor it's really easy to get syntax errors

Answer (score -1):

```
public String Do(){
     string s = " hello, click <a href='" + Url.Action("Index") +"' > here </a>";

     return s;
}
```

then if you call {Controller}/Do you will have your string

**EDITED**

Marco

Comment: Html.ActionLink has to be evalutated

Comment: @Omu may the UrlHelper can help you, I edit my answer and tried out and it work, I hope is the thing that you wanted!